# DownloadManager set title change my filename

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I used DownloadManager in my application to download file from internet. 
Here's my code.

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) ui.activity.getSystemService(Activity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse("http://dl.appvn.com/appvn.apk");
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);


request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                  .
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"appvn.apk");

request.setTitle("AppStoreVN");

request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");

downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

I used setTitle & setDescription to change the info show on Notification bar. But it also change my file name like title ("AppStoreVN" while it should be "appvn.apk").
Anyone have ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> for getting name of downloading file i used:

```
String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(mDownloadFileUrl, null,
                MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mDownloadFileUrl));
```

> then for setting title and description of DownloadManager

```
request.setDescription(nameOfFile);
request.setTitle(nameOfFile);
```

> Then for setting actual file name of downloaded file in directory path

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
 /*here the name of file is set*/nameOfFile);
```

hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I came here finding what I thought was the same issue as when I look in the "downloads" app on the phone I see the title of the file instead of the .apk

I found if I use a file explorer though the actual filename is correct, it's just the downloads app shows the content database details and must set a title to be the same as the notification title.

If it won't parse the file, look at logcat as the location the file had been created at didn't match what I had expected it to be.

Answer (score -1):

you can set Destination like below in which you can specify file name too.

```
setDestinationUri()
```

**or**

```
setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/mnt/sdcard/", "test.jpg");
```